# how to call a java action when changes in databse

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

hii i am working on spring and hibernate, i have a situation when i want to call a method when changes is done in data base means like notification whenever a new notification is come then my page automatically show the no of notification, i have done this work using timer but its not good it because it call repeatedly and load on server is increased unusually so please tell me is there any way to listen the data base and call the method only when a new entry ios done or any change is made on data base

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Trigger from database to java program using sys_exec():

see https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys

- Use an hibernate entity listener. This only work if hibernate has excusive access to database.

see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you have a web interface which should show a notification, if there's a new DB entry?

Then you've first got to choose one of Jose Luis Martin's suggestions, in order to have the notification on the server side. And then you have to forward this notification to the client. For this there are a few possibilities:

1. (What you already did): Use polling (sending a request from client to server every x seconds, asking for new entries):  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)
2. Let the server push the data to the client. This is the more "modern" solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

I'd suggest using the second approach in combination with some framework like Atmosphere: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

This framework supports several different ways of communication, with fallbacks etc.

---

### EDIT:

If you really just want the information inside a server method, **and** the information hasn't to be 100% precise, you could also use a timer on the server to count the new items every 30 seconds and kinda *cache* the result for the client requests.